# Robustness Weights in LOESS behaving strangely

Tags: python, robust, smoothing, loess

I've been playing around with writing my own LOESS module in Python (2 reasons: first, I wanted the practice, and second, the implementation in `statsmodels` doesn't compute confidence intervals).

The implementation is based primarily on the original LOESS paper (Cleveland, 1988, *Journal of the American Statistical Association*) and on this presentation from *Michigan State* (linked in the code comments).

All went well until I tried implementing the robustness weights (see slides 18-19 in the presentation). The completely mess-up the smoothing.

As an example, I downloaded debt-to-GDP data from FRED to smooth. After the first iteration (before robustness weights are applied), it smoothes rather well:

[image: Debt-to-GDP, initial smooth in green, original data series in blue]

However, after just two additional iteration with the robustness weights, here's what starts to happen:

[image: Same data, LOESS after two robustness iterations, T=6]

Do you have any idea what might be going on? I suspect there is something wrong with the robustness weights vector, or with the way I multiply the weights, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class LoessPy:

    def __init__(self, X, Y, m = 0.3, p = 3, t = 10., iters=50):
        #where X and Y are numpy arrays
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.m = m
        self.p = p
        self.t = t
        self.iter = iters
        self.mad = 0
        self.cost = 0

        self.n = len(X)
        self.window = np.int(np.floor(self.n*m))

        self.weights = np.zeros((self.n, self.n))
        self.Yhat = np.zeros_like(Y)
        self.res = np.zeros_like(Y)
        self.res_weights = np.ones_like(Y)

        self.betas = np.zeros_like(self.weights)

    def find_neighbors(self, x):
        diffs = np.empty((self.n, 2))
        diffs[:,1] = np.abs(self.X - x)
        diffs[:,0] = range(self.n)
        d_sorted = diffs[diffs[:,1].argsort()]
        n_indices = d_sorted[range(self.window),0]
        return n_indices.astype(int), self.X[n_indices.tolist()]

    def weight_cubic(self, x0, x1, span):
        z = (x0-x1)/(span/2.)
        return (1-(abs(z)**3))**3 if abs(z) < 1 else 0

    def assign_weights(self, x, i):
        indices, neighbors = self.find_neighbors(x)
        sorted_ind = np.sort(indices)
        span = np.max(neighbors) - np.min(neighbors)
        weights = np.zeros(len(indices))
        for a, ind in enumerate(indices):
            w = self.weight_cubic(x, neighbors[a], span)
            order = np.argwhere(sorted_ind == ind)
            weights[order] = w
            self.weights[i, ind] = w
        res_weights = self.res_weights[indices]
        return np.multiply(weights,res_weights)

    def local_WLS(self, x, i):
        weights = self.assign_weights(x, i)
        ind, neighbors = self.find_neighbors(x)
        ys = self.Y[ind.tolist()]
        yw = np.multiply(weights, ys)
        xw = np.multiply(weights, neighbors)
        betahat = np.dot(np.transpose(xw),ys) / np.dot(np.transpose(xw),xw)
        intercept = np.mean(yw) - betahat*np.mean(xw)
        yhat = x*betahat + intercept
        self.betas[i, ind] = betahat
        self.Yhat[i] = yhat

    def fit(self):
        self.cost = 0
        for iteration in range(self.iter):
            for i, x in enumerate(self.X):
                self.local_WLS(x,i)
            self.res = self.Y - self.Yhat
            self.mad = np.median( np.abs(self.res - np.median(self.res)) )
            for i, m in enumerate(self.res):
                z = m / (self.t * self.mad)
                v = (1-(z**2))**2 if np.abs(z) < 1 else 0
                self.res_weights[i] = v
            cost = np.sum(self.res**2)
            print cost
            if cost == self.cost: break
            self.cost = cost
        return self.cost

    def variance(self):
        self.shat = np.zeros_like(self.Yhat)
        identity = np.identity(self.n)
        self.R = np.multiply(self.X, self.betas)
        self.c = np.dot((identity - self.R), np.transpose(identity - self.R))
        self.trace = np.trace(self.c)
        self.sigma2 = np.sum(self.res**2) / self.trace
        self.shat = np.sqrt(self.sigma2) * np.sqrt(np.sum(self.R**2, 1))

    def plot(self):
        plt.figure(0)
        self.variance()
        self.ciPlus = self.Yhat + 2*self.shat
        self.ciMinus = self.Yhat - 2*self.shat
        plt.plot(self.X,self.Y)
        plt.plot(self.X, self.Yhat)
        plt.plot(self.X, self.ciPlus)
        plt.plot(self.X, self.ciMinus)
        plt.fill_between(self.X, self.ciPlus, self.ciMinus, facecolor='aqua', alpha=0.3)



'''
GOAL: implement a LOESS module for python based on numpy 
that smoothes a given X-Y dataset,
while also providing standard errors and confidence intervals, 
consulted primarily this presentation
http://polisci.msu.edu/jacoby/icpsr/regress3/lectures/week4/15.Loess.pdf

STEP 0:
Have a bivariate dataset of X and Y

STEP 1:
Choose the windows size for finding nearest neighbors
Let window width = m (percent of the sample)

STEP 2:
Weight the data using the tricube weight function
Let the scaled distance between any two observations based on X be:
z = (x1-x0)/h
Where h = half width of the window (m/2)

Then the weight function is defined as
W(z) = (1-abs(z)^3)^3 if abs(z) < 1 else 0

STEP 3:
Locally weighted least squares
Using the weights from step 2, a polynomial regression is applied to the focal observation,
using only the neighbor observations to minimize weighted sum of squares
The degree of polynomial is a parameter p

Y_i = A + B1(x_i - x0) + B2(x_i - x0)^2 + ... + E_i

Then get the fitted value for the focal X value and plot it

STEP 4:
Do steps 1 - 3 for each observation
Connect fitted values to produce the regression curve
There are no coefficient estimates - graph is essential

STEP 5 (optional):
Adjusting for outliers (robustness)

Calculate residuals E_i = Y_i - Yhat_i
Calculate median absolute deviation MAD = median( abs(E_i - median(E_i)) )
Calculate resistance weights using the bisquare weight function:
z = E_i / (t x MAD) where t is a parameter
v_i = (1-z^2)^2 if abs(z) < 1 else 0
(t = 6 corresponds to approx 4 std dev = exclude observations with P < 0.0001)

Refit the regression using old and new weights

Repeat until convergence

STEP 6:

Estimating variance
Vhat (yhat_i) = S^2 * sum (w_ij)^2

Confidence intervals

+- 2 sqrt(V_hat)
'''
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Debugging your code isn't on-topic here, but questions about the algorithm itself should be. You may need to reframe your question somewhat to get it within the scope here.

Comment: For what's worth it looks like you have strong edge effects. I would recommend first trying your implementation where you know the answer and then try it to a real life dataset.